# Unable to resolve internal server error(500 response code) in Jmeter

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-5.0, jmeter-4.0, jmeter-3.2

[Internal Server Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VIbPv.png)

[SSL- jmeter.properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UFTtJ.png)

[Cookie - jmeter.properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oPZoZ.png)

Recorded those 4 endpoints in Chrome(Incognito) using blazemeter extension.
Website uses SSL cipher suite ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384, with DH-PARAM: 2048 bit.
After changing from default TLS to SSL(in jmeter.properties) & CookieManager.check.cookies = false still unable to resolve internal server error for last 2 endpoints. Beginner to using Jmeter. Already went thr all the sols in stackoverflow.

Comment: In Jmeter properties , do you need SSLv3 ?? Checked menudrive.com certificate and it's tls1.3 . SSL/TLS are used interchangeable but today's standard is TLS 1.3 and SSL is outdated one.

Comment: you have not mentioned what does internal server error has request and response , details in response might give more details.

Comment: Hey @mbshambharkar, pls look into these pics -  https://imgur.com/A4ptnPA

https://imgur.com/RfqqDgy

https://imgur.com/vW3p90A

Comment: Unfortunately attached screenshot doesn't give any more insight, looking at them it looks pretty normal call and server should not fail such request. One thing is missing in this screenshot- response message , it is html page as we can see but what it says is not clear from screenshot. You can copy the response content to simple text file and rename as html and open it in browser to see what content it has, this might give exact error code server is throwing